# How to change data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a big problem and cant find a solution. While working on a project I found some user credentials as GET- Parameters in the URL (some external programmers where sloppy). This should be removed (obviously) but I cant' find a way to change (remove) old data.

It would be great to have a solution for removing all GET- Parameters from string containg a @- sign. Is there some way to access the old data in Google Analytics and modify it?

It would be great if somebody can point out a solution.

All the best

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change data that has already been collected (the only sort-a kind-a exception is query time imports in GA 360 accounts which are applied to historical data). So your best chance is to export your data to an external tools and consolidate your data there (or if you just need a total of urls without the query parameter then use an ad-hoc-filter in the data table for the url path and the head of the table will show the total).

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Eike is saying right, It is not possible to change the previously collected data in Google Analytics. but for future you can filter out those url from collecting the data and stop to view it in Google Analytics.